# Why are no data stored after persist and restart

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.2

I've been trying to learn JPA,EJB,servlets, things are working ok for the most part.
But whatever I do I can't actually get hibernate to find anything i've persisted after I restart the application on the wildfly server.

it's really frustrating there's no error message, nothing in the logs and when I check that my object is in the entity manager with .contains it's does return true.

I've tried adding a `flush()`

I've tried adding my class to the `persistance.xml`. (it's meant to find it automatically right ?)

I've tried changing the generation.database.action to : create, drop-and-create, drop and none; no luck.

here are the files if anybody could help it'd be great because i'm very confused rn.

persistance.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EJBColis">
        <class>jpa.Colis</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EJBColis.java

```
package ejb;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import jpa.Colis;
import jpa.Mesure;
import jpa.Position;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EJBColis {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    
    /**
     * Constructeur sans parametre obligatoire
     */
    public EJBColis() {
    }
    
    public Colis addColis(double poid,double valeur,String origin,String destination,Position p ) {
        Colis m = new Colis(poid, valeur, origin, destination, p);
        em.persist(m);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(m);
        return m;
    }
 
    public Colis findColis(long id) {
        Colis m = em.find(Colis.class, id);
        return m;
    }
    
    public Position changePosition(long ColisId,double longitude,double lat,String origin,String destination) {
        Position m = new Position(longitude,lat, origin, destination);
        Colis c = findColis(ColisId);
        c.setPosition(m);
        em.persist(c);
        em.flush();
        return m;
    }
    
    public Position findPosition(long id) {
        Position m = em.find(Position.class, id);
        return m;
    }
```

}

addColisServlet.java :

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import ejb.EJBColis;
import jpa.Colis;
import jpa.Mesure;
import jpa.Position;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddColisServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AddColisServlet")
public class AddColisServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    // injection de la reference de l'ejb
    @EJB
    private EJBColis ejb;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddColisServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        double Poid = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("poid"));
        double valeur = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valeur")) ;
        String origine = request.getParameter("origine");
        String destination = request.getParameter("destination");
        Position position = null;
        
        
        
        
        Colis m = ejb.addColis(Poid, valeur, origine, destination, position);       
        // ajout de la mesure dans la requete
        request.setAttribute("Colis",m);
        // transfert a la JSP d'affichage
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/showColis.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

the html page that calls addColisServlet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Manipulation des comptes bancaires</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" >
</head>
<body>
<h1>Manipulation des comptes bancaires</h1>
    <h2>tracker un colis :</h2>
    <form action="ShowColisServlet" method="post">
        ID : <input type="number" name="ID">
        <input type="submit" value="valider">
    </form>
    <h2>Creer un colis</h2>
    <form action="AddColisServlet" method="post">
        Poid : <input type="number" name="poid">
        valeur : <input type="number" name="valeur">
        origine : <input type="text" name="origine">
        destination : <input type="text" name="destination">
        <input type="submit" value="valider">
    </form>
    <h2>modifier position d'un colis:</h2>
    <form action="ModifColisServlet" method="post">
        ID : <input type="text" name="ID">
        latitude : <input type="number" name="lat">
        longitude : <input type="number" name="long">
        emplacement : <input type="text" name="emplacement">
        etat : <input type="text" name="etat">
        <input type="submit" value="chercher">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

also i setup a github link to the code it's an eclipse project :

https://github.com/vvhitefox/ColisEJB

Comment: what kind of database do you use? what does your datasource look like?

Comment: tbh i have no idea i think eclipse does everything on it's own i haven't had to setup a database at all.

Comment: i forgot to mention i deploy to wildfly 24 i'll edit the question.

Comment: Flush doesn't do anything itself other than force JPA to issue SQL statements - you must be an a transactional context and commit that context for the data to be persisted in the DB.  But if you don't have a persistent database setup, it might not be a persistent database and is using an In-memory database that is wiped out when your app restarts. Setup a database and control it yourself to determine if something else is wrong.

Comment: ah! ok so it's saves it to a database that ends up discarded when i end the program. i'll try to setup a real database and I'll get back to you. thx.